# How to install CouchDB on Windows

Tags: windows, installation, couchdb, wizard

This might seem like a basic question, but let me explain.

I'm currently trying to get CouchDB running on Windows. Usually (from what I can tell watching several YT tutorials) you just go to couchdb.apache.org/download and download the windowsx64 version. Then open it and a install wizard should appear.

However when I download the file I get a file named "fd15d91c1e214c3451bef296564086f6a9266e848d57eaa8ac596e3765939578" which isn't openable and doesn't give me a wizard.

Is the current CouchDB installation corrupted? Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: That's not normal. Try another browser with this link : https://dl.bintray.com/apache/couchdb/win/2.0.0.2/couchdb-2.0.0.2.msi

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just tried http://couchdb.apache.org/, chose the Download link from the top navigation bar, then Windows(x64) for version 2.1.0.  This kicked-off downloading the file apache-couchdb-2.1.0.msi.

Definitely try another browser or restart your machine.

Comment: Changed the browser and it worked. Didn't work with Firefox though :/
Thank you for your answer!